# Set Focus Mode programatically

Tags: android

Is it possible to set [focus mode](https://www.blog.google/products/android/android-focus-mode) programatically in Android?
I was hoping for a system API like the following, but don't see focus mode in the system APIs.

`Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.FOCUS_MODE, 1);`

Comment: As far as I checked there is no official documentation regarding this and there is no mention of FOCUS_MODE constant also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible as of answering this question. Focus Mode is a separate app, a part of Google's Digital Wellbeing app, and is not a part of the AOSP.